# Capturing data with jQuery to use with PHP - non-standard implementation question

Tags: php, jquery

I have a unique setup in my program where I have multiple  fields, each with non-standard attributes.

For instance (general example):

```
<textarea id=1 name='text1' level=1 parent=0></textarea>
<textarea id=2 name='text2' level=1 parent=1></textarea>
<textarea id=3 name='text3' level=2 parent=2></textarea>
<textarea id=4 name='text4' level=2 parent=3></textarea>
```

I want to use jQuery to capture each individual elements and their attributes and send them to my PHP script.

I have yet to be able to figure this one out using a clean method.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what all these attributes will be?

Comment: Yes.  I'm creating the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each one of them and serialize them using a jQuery class selector?

Answer (score 0):

[How about something this](http://jsfiddle.net/f5feV/):

```
var attrs = ['name', 'level', 'parent'];
var result = {'name': [], 'level': [], 'parent': []};

for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
    $('textarea').each(function () {
        result[attrs[i]].push($(this).attr(attrs[i]));
    });
}
console.log(result);
```